# Django URL page parameter and another parameter

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

how can I fix this?
In my template I have this:

```
<a href="{% url 'hp:category-filtered-page-blog' category=category page=page_obj.next_page_number %}">Next</a>
```

I would like a pagination with another url parameter.
So my CBV:

```
class CategoryFilteredBlogList(ListView):
    template_name = 'blog.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 1
    allow_empty = True

    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        log_visitor(self.request, 'blog sort on category: {0}'.format(self.kwargs['category']))
        return super(CategoryFilteredBlogList, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_queryset(self):
        print(self.kwargs['category'])
        self.category = get_object_or_404(Category, title=self.kwargs['category'])
        return Post.objects.filter(category__title__contains=self.category).order_by('-id')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CategoryFilteredBlogList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['category'] = self.category
        return context
```

my url config:

```
url(r'^blog/category/(?P<category>.+)$', CategoryFilteredBlogList.as_view(), name='category-filtered-blog'),
url(r'^blog/category/(?P<category>.+)/page/(?P<page>\w+)$', CategoryFilteredBlogList.as_view(), name='category-filtered-page-blog'),
```

It prints: 'stuff/page/2' but I only would 'stuff'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the first url pattern is matching everything including the slash itself:

```
url(r'^blog/category/(?P<category>.+)$', CategoryFilteredBlogList.as_view(), name='category-filtered-blog'),
```

Demo of what is happening:

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile('^blog/category/(?P<category>.+)$')
>>> pattern.match('blog/category/stuff/page/2').group(1)
'stuff/page/2'
```

To fix it, just remove the first url pattern and let the second one capture the `category`.

Demo:

```
>>> pattern = re.compile('^blog/category/(?P<category>.+)/page/(?P<page>\w+)$')
>>> pattern.match('blog/category/stuff/page/2').group(1)
'stuff'
```

If you want the page to be optional and allow urls like `blog/category/stuff` to work, you can swap the urls so that you first check for the page to be there:

```
url(r'^blog/category/(?P<category>.+)/page/(?P<page>\w+)$', CategoryFilteredBlogList.as_view(), name='category-filtered-page-blog'),
url(r'^blog/category/(?P<category>.+)$', CategoryFilteredBlogList.as_view(), name='category-filtered-blog'),
```

Comment: Holy moley! He said swap the urls and it works. :-) Thank you and for all thank you for the description!!!